# Change default backend language programmatically

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, multilingual, external-script

I have a component installed which doesn't provide multilingual support.

If I import data via the API, I can't import in a different language, only in the default backend language.

Unfortunately, the owner of the component doesn't want to implement the multilingual support in the API.

In this case, I need to change the default backend language in my script which is using the API.

I want to import in language1, change the default language to language2, then import in language2.

The Component is SobiPor (https://www.sigsiu.net/center/sobipro-component)
With this Component you can Import Data via CLI (https://www.sigsiu.net/center/applications/272-importexport-application)
Unfortunately i can't give out sample data because of the privacy policy.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I have tried to improve the English/grammar in your question.  If I have misunderstood/damaged your post, you are welcome to re-edit the question to make it more accurate.  May we know the name of the component?  Can you show us how you are importing text? May we see some sample data?  Please add these details as an edit (not a comment). These bits of context help volunteers to better understand the situation.  Please take the [tour] and fill out your Profile (...that's where you can tell people that your real name is Aurelius, if you wish).

Comment: Do you really need to change the site/backend default language or do you just need to change the language for the user doing the import when they get to do the second import? If you change the default for that period of time that it is changed, everyone gets a different language displayed. Have you looked at /plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php as it appears to a lot of the work when switching between languages including overriding the default language with what is defined in the users profile. There might be code there that can help you.

Comment: The only solution that you can apply on this is to get and set the data as per the language of the content by providing a language switcher, for all available languages you may need to get the data specific to language and can store it as Joomla does for articles. If you can explain more about the extension we may guide you in a better way.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa for improving my English :-)
I've added some more information

Comment: @Irata the Sobi Support tell that the only way to import multilanguage data via CLI ist to change default admin language.